# Rails multi level association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

New to Ruby, Rails, and OOP in general. I've been through the "Ruby on Rails Tutorial: Learn Web Development with Rails" and about 80% through "Agile Web Development with Rails 4" but I can't visually figure this out. I was hoping someone can help me understand, maybe I'm wording it wrong.

Models: User, Team, Membership, Order, OrderLine

It's a pretty basic setup. (short hand, if you will...)
Team belongs_to :user (owner, not terribly relevant here)
Users has_many :teams through: :memberships
Team has_many :users through: :memberships
OrderLine belongs_to :team
*Note an OrderLine is assigned to a team, not a whole Order.*

I'm trying to display all OrderLines which are associated with the currently logged in user (current_user). While this doesn't actually work, I feel it's close to producing. It also feels super dirty.

```
    def index
        @memberships = current_user.memberships.ids
        membership_list = @memberships.join(", ")
        @OrderLines = OrderLine.where("team_id IN (?)", membership_list)
    end
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
# Model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :owned_team, :class_name => "Team"
  has_many :teams
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :order_lines, through: :memberships

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :faction
  belongs_to :region
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User"
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
  has_many :order_lines

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team
  has_many :order_lines, through: :team

# Controller
@OrderLines = current_user.order_lines
```

Some times all you need is a break.